# sqldeveloper wont open

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've just installed Oracle 11g express on Windows 10, but I can't seem to launch SQLDeveloper.
i'm double clicking the sqldeveloper but nothing happens, no error , nothing.

sqldeveloper version: 20.2.0.175.1842-x64

I've also tried to run from sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.exe
and I've tried launching sqldeveloper.exe from the console, but I'm not getting error messages in the console.
[image]

how should i check what is the problem?
i have install java and java jdk8u271

this is my set:

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\snirbenyosef\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=SNIRBENYOSEC8E4
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\snirbenyosef
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\snirbenyosef\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\SNIRBENYOSEC8E4
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Tools\Applications;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\snirbenyosef\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=8e0a
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\SNIRBE~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\SNIRBE~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=SNIRBENYOSEC8E4
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=SNIRBENYOSEC8E4
USERNAME=snirbenyosef
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\snirbenyosef
windir=C:\Windows
```

Comment: please post a screenshot of this - "I've also tried to run from sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.exe and I've tried launching sqldeveloper.exe from the console, but I'm not getting error messages in the console"

Comment: @thatjeffsmith i'have add a img.

Comment: what is \\Mac\home... that doesn't look like a windows path? also, what version of sql developer are you running?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith its a mac path, but i'm using parallels for mac. its a virtual box with windows 10.
sql developer version :
sqldeveloper-20.2.0.175.1842-x64

Comment: sqldev will run natively on your mac, try it there - it should work in your virtualized windows, but i've never tried it there

Comment: @thatjeffsmith its the same. not opening. but what is the problem its just a virtual windows. its the same as normal one.

Comment: on the mac, can you get sdcli (in that same bin dir) to respond, give output? what do you get if you run java -version ?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith
what is sdcli ?

java version return:
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: sdcli on mac to nothing also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223375/discussion-between-thatjeffsmith-and-snir-ben-yosef).

Answer (score 0):

just move the sql developer to desktop of windows and not the linked to mac. solved it.